# Statistics och folders and file structure on a Linux server

Tags: database, linux, statistics, data-analysis

I need to produce statistics for files that are stored on a Linux network share and would like to be able run a shell script or program locally on the network share to produce data points with the following attributes:

path (or relativepath) | filename | filesize | datecreated | datechanged | dateaccessed

There are roughly 1–2 million files (8TB) and I want to explore the dataset to get a grasp of the organization and balance of the file types (as determined by a combination of file name and path) in relation to the total number of files and total amount of storage.

**Questions:**

1. What is an efficient way to traverse the file system and get this data?
2. What kind of database would you recommend to explore this kind of data with statistics at different levels in the hierarchy?

Comment: What kind of queries do you expect to be able to answer with this database?

Comment: Useful results from queries: The folder tree structure for 3 levels starting from the root. The number of files and total size for each folder. All the data points within folder subtree.

Comment: I plan to add attributes to the data points while exploring distributions of sizes, filenames, and age at different levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up using to solve the problem:

1. Linux commands `find` and `fstat` were used generate the dataset as a plain text file.
2. Python’s `pandas` and `exifread` libraries were used to enrich and analyze the dataset.